# Dedicated Server by Unity3d Service AND online Matchmaking. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dedicated-server, unity3d-unet, matchmaking

I'm developing a tactical RPG like Disgaea or Fire Emblem for PC, with the exception it is online/2 person PvP so it needs a dedicated server to avoid cheating.

Steps of what I am planning to do:

1) Player creates a map with my map editor

2) Player uploads the map to Unity dedicated Server. I think it is cheap and comfy.

3) Player's map is showing on MATCHMAKING list as a room for anyone to join and start playing.

I did some research and figured that Unet dedicated server does not support online matchmaking. Or does it? I'm a bit confused.

I need some clarifications:

A) Is the above plan possible?

B) I searched in the store for Matchmaking on a dedicated Server and ended up to "Master Server Kit" asset. Can this be the solution?

C) Are Unity Devs, (if the above plan is not possible) working on that direction, somehow for future releases?

D) If I rent Unity dedicated Server Service bandwidth (which I really wish this to happen cause for a turn-based game is quite cheap) what are my publishing options? Can I distribute it through STEAM?

The peer2peer (server host AND client by one of the two players) is a NO GO!

Comment: Greetings, by Unity dedicated Server, you mean " MasterServer" ?
Also since I have no knowledge of the mentioned games, what are your minimum functional requirements for the server?
Example, Pathing, geodata, collisions etc....

Comment: MasterServer that stores player position, player stats, NO collisions, nothing real-time just prediction, by end of turn.

Comment: I'm not sure if MasterServer (which by the way is legacy I believe) have the functionality to upload things or store positions or stats (to database for example) you might need to write these things on your own which if you go down this path is easier to do it yourself with exactly the things you need. But then you will require to host your own machine.